Find the Bruhat decomposition of an invertible matrix in Python
Is there a quick way to obtain the Bruhat decomposition of an invertible integer matrix in Python?
This means for a given invertible matrix M to find a decomposition M=LPU, where L is lower triangular, U is upper triangular and P is a permutation matrix.
Thanks for any help!

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu.html#scipy.linalg.lu

@lastchance Thank you, but this is something else. I want a LPU factorisation and not a PLU factorisation! The LPU factorisation has the advantage that P is uniquely determined by M, while this is not true for the PLU factorisation.
